# Is this question too easy or am I getting it wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

In my homework, I am asked to find the limit

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{x}{e^x}}$$

But obviously, you could just substitute $x = 0$:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{x}{e^x}} = \lim\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{0}{e^0}}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{0}{1}}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}{0} = 0$$

This seemed – by far – too easy. Is this *really* all there is to it? Is my solution valid?

**Edit**:

Apparently, this is valid. Still, I do wonder if these are the only conditions that allow me to actually substitute my limit variable.

Comment: Yup, that's it. If you want, you can justify why your substitution was valid using common properties of limits.

Comment: @AlexG. Would it be enough to mention that, by substituting, we don't stumble across undefined or undeterminate values? :)

Comment: I had a slightly tangential question: I tried using L'hôpital's Rule and got $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 1/e^x$. But then when I substitute $x=0$, I get $1$ and not $0$. So L'hôpital's Rule fails, but I like to know how and when this method doesn't work.

Comment: @Glacier We use L'Hôpital's rule only and only if we have a $\pm\infty/\infty$ or a $0/0$ form  which isn't the case here since if you plug in $x=0$ you get a well defined value $0/1=0$.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع: Don't forget $0 \cdot \infty$. ;)

Comment: @chiru Hmm... I don't think so, look at [Wolfram's definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) of L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Sorry, my last sentence wasn't very precise — What I meant to say was: Don't forget that $0\cdot\infty$ is undeterminate as well. You can rewrite this into a fraction as can bee seen [here](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/inf_times_zero.html).

Comment: @chiru True, but then you would just have a $0/0$ or $\pm\infty/\infty$ again. ;-)

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Touché. :)

Comment: I think of these as "were you listening to a word I said" questions. If you have a basic understanding of the concepts, you can solve them in seconds. Don't be surprised if you get a lot of them.

Comment: You seemed surprised at how easy this one was, but the point of problems like this is to impress upon students that techniques for resolving undefined or indeterminate values (like L'hôpital's Rule) can give you the wrong answer if applied in this context.

Comment: I know. I was referring to the phrasing of the title question, "Is this question too easy...". This question is very easy, but from a teaching perspective the objective of such a question is not to be a difficult limit problem, but to catch students using such techniques inappropriately.

Comment: Aren't you glad the answer to the title question wasn't "both"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The limit is correct, but you have to justify that you can do the substitution. In general
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$$
holds only if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. So to answer your question: you can do the substitution only if the function $f$ is continuous and of course the function must be defined at the point $x_0$. Since $f(x) = x/e^x$ is continuous for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and the value $f(0)$ is defined we have that
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{e^x} = \frac{0}{e^0}=0. $$

Comment: This answer is much more precise than mine and also answers the additional question that I've edited into my original question. **+1**

Comment: Is this actually an answer? The definition of continuity itself involves limits, you're just using circular reasoning.

Comment: @Mehrdad: depends which definition you use; the one I was taught doesn't use limits.  (According to Wikipedia this is called the Weierstrass definition.  Since it is more general, I'd argue that it is preferable.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The Weierstrass definition of continuity literally **is** the statement that $f$ is continuous at $c$ whenever $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$... so I'm not sure what you're talking about. Using the Weierstrass definition is circular reasoning by its very nature. The only thing you can really do to avoid circular reasoning is to actually *do* the epsilon-delta proof, otherwise your assumption (that the proof holds) is exactly what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @Mehrdad: the Weierstrass definition is trivially equivalent to the statement using the limit plus the definition of the limit, true.  But you wouldn't generally actually calculate the limit in order to prove continuity.  MJD's answer fills in some of the parts this answer skips lightly over.

Comment: Given the context of this being a HW exercise, I don't think this is necessarily circular reasoning. The definition of continuity is the statement that, if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$, then $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$, but this answer uses the converse statement, namely that if $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$. Of course one then has to establish that $x/e^x$ is continuous at $x=0$. If you use the definition of continuity to establish that, then sure, it's circular reasoning, but depending on OP's background, it could be taken as a statement which needs no explicit proof.

Answer (score 17):

One of your questions is “When can I substitute the limit variable”, which I take to mean

> “When is $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)?”$$

A sufficient condition for this to work is that $f$ must be continuous at $a$.  (In fact, this is the definition of what it means for a function to be continuous at $a$!)  This doesn't immediately answer the question, because continuity can be very complicated.  However, the following rules cover a great many situations:

1. Constant functions $x\mapsto c$ are continuous everywhere  (“$x\mapsto c$” means “the function that takes $x$ and maps it to $c$”.)
2. The identity function $x\mapsto x$ is continuous everywhere
3. The addition and multiplication functions $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ are continuous everywhere
4. The division function $(x,y)\mapsto \frac xy$ is continuous  except where the denominator $y$ is $0$
5. The exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous everywhere
6. Compositions of continuous functions are continuous

Here we have the  function $x\mapsto \frac x{e^x}$.  The function $x\mapsto x$ is continuous by (2).  The function $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous by (5).  The quotient of these will be continuous by (6) and (5), except when the denominator $e^x$ is $0$—but it never is. So $x\mapsto\frac x{e^x}$ is continuous everywhere.

The upshot of all this is that $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac x{e^x} = \frac a{e^a}$$ for *all* $a$, and in particular for $a=0$.

To consider the simplest possible counterexample, take $x\mapsto \frac1x$.  This is continuous everywhere except possibly at $x=0$, and indeed we have $\lim_{x\to a}\frac1x = \frac 1a$ for all $a\ne 0$.  For $a=0$ there is no limit.

A more interesting counterexample is $x\mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$.  Again, we have $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{\sin a}{a}$ for all $a\ne 0$.  For $a=0$ we have the interesting and nontrivial fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: **Attention readers:** this _is_ the answer! The one flagged by the PO is a circular definition.

Comment: @caya Can  you provide me a proof that $e^{x}$ is continuous everywhere(which this answer rests on)? Can you do it without a limit?

Comment: If I remember correctly (in Spivak's) $e^x$ is defined through its Taylor series and proved continuous that way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x%2Fe%5Ex%29%2C+x+to+0), the solution $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{e^x} = 0$ is indeed correct.

Also, I think that my substitution is justifiable, as by performing the substitution, we don't have the problem of getting undefined or indeterminate values.

Comment: This really would be better if incorporated into your question. You seem to be asking another question rather than answering your original question (even though you've mentioned the W|A answer).

Comment: Thanks. I've moved the questioning part to the original question.